# Convert an object to datetime in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe like the one below.  How can I transform the reviewTime column to date format?  Currently, the reviewTime is an object.

```
 overall    reviewTime
 6          10 19,2013
 5          06 18, 2014
 4          05 5, 2013
```

overall           1682 non-null object
reviewTime        1682 non-null object

Comment: Normally it is done with `pd.to_datetime()`, but you can also use `apply` and  ´datetime.datetime.strftime()`. This needs some cleaning first though

Answer (score 1):

Replace all `,` and spaces by `''`, then use `pd.to_datetime` with format specified i.e

```
df['reviewTimeclean'] = pd.to_datetime(df['reviewTime'].str.replace('[,\s]',''),format='%m%d%Y')

# Also pd.to_datetime(df['reviewTime'].str.replace('[^\d]',''),format='%m%d%Y')

    overall   reviewTime reviewTimeclean
0        6   10 19,2013      2013-10-19
1        5  06 18, 2014      2014-06-18
2        4   05 5, 2013      2013-05-05
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

data = {'overall': {0: 6, 1: 5, 2: 4},
        'reviewTime': {0: '10 19,2013', 1: '06 18, 2014', 2: '05 5, 2013'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Clean
df.reviewTime = df.reviewTime.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(i.strip() for i in x.split(",")))

# To_datetime and apply (commented out)
df.reviewTime = pd.to_datetime(df.reviewTime)
#df.reviewTime = df.reviewTime.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x,"%m %d %Y"))


print(df)
```

Returns:

```
   overall reviewTime
0        6 2013-10-19
1        5 2014-06-18
2        4 2013-05-05
```

Comment: Good one striping spaces and then joining with space after splitting, I was working on that with regex couldn't get so thought of removing all extra separators.

Comment: @Dark Thanks! My intention is to spend more time with regex. It's too powerful.

Comment: Yeah regex indeed is very powerful, and is much like math need more practice and time to get more intuition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code:

```
import datetime

a='12 19,2013' #sample input

a=a.split()
a[1]=a[1].split(',')
b=[]
b.append(int(a[0]))
b.append(int(a[1][0]))
b.append(int(a[1][1]))

t=datetime.date(b[2],b[0],b[1])

print(t)
```

Result:

```
2013-12-19
```

Comment: And my suggestion is to always provide a more generalised solution, since its a pandas question :)

Answer (score 0):

Let us try something new ..

```
import re


df['reviewTime']=list(map(lambda x : re.sub('[^0-9]','', x),df['reviewTime'].values))


df['reviewTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['reviewTime'].astype(str),format='%m%d%Y')
df
Out[352]: 
  reviewTime
0 2013-10-19
1 2014-06-18
2 2013-05-05
```

More info

```
list(map(lambda x : re.sub('[^0-9]','', x),df['reviewTime'].values))

Out[344]: ['10192013', '06182014', '0552013']
```